# Giving envelope access to other users in the account while sending envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

We have integrated Docusign on our application. We are using Docusign sdk's to send envelopes in bulk.

Use case - User A is sending a batch (envelopes in bulk) and wants user B to having some visibility on the envelopes sent. This is optional meaning user A might choose not to set visibility for user B while sending the second batch. Is there a way in which I can specify this while using the bulk send Api (bulkEnvelopesApi.createBulkSendRequest).

If not are there any possible ways to implement this ? I have gone through the documentation for shared access, but it does not align with our use case.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this - make these users CC for these envelopes.

CC recipients have access to the envelopes that they are CC on.

By "access" I mean they can view them, they cannot modify them etc.

If you need full control (anything and everything including deleting the envelope) than you do have to use the Shared Access feature which you said "does not align with our use case" and you may need to explain why?